# Combine queries to grab foreign key value from different able based on result in mssql

Tags: php, sql-server

I have to work with a mssql database that I have no control over, so sadly, I can't change the structure at all. This database is setup so that there are 2 tables `Entry` and  `Area`. In the `Area` table, there is a column `sArea` that I need to look up based on a value `ixEntry`. In the `Entry` table, I can do a look up (the variables are PHP variables):

```
SELECT sTitle,ixCategory,ixArea FROM Entry WHERE ixEntry='$ixEntry'
```

and then do a second query

```
SELECT sArea FROM Area WHERE ixArea='{$return['ixArea']}'
```

Which works just fine, except with the way that the network is setup, there is considerably more overhead time with two queries.

How can I combine these two queries so that I have a result that would be the equivalent of `SELECT sTitle,ixCategory,sArea FROM Entry WHERE ixEntry='$ixEntry'` as if `sArea` were in the Entry table, not ixArea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT a.sArea FROM Entry e
        INNER JOIN Area a ON e.ixArea = a.ixArea
            WHERE e.ixEntry='$ixEntry'
```

Comment: Though I did have to change the selects to include the other fields that I wanted.